# Choosing appropriate screen size to work with

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, screen

I have got rather general question about making Adaptive Layout in iOS App.

When creating new project in Xcode you have ability to choose with which screen size you can start working:
[image: Screen sizes]

I have noticed that if you place a square `UIView` on iPhone SE screen and then connect Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom constraints - this view displays correctly on every other screen. But if you perform same actions on iPhone X, then this same shape would be corrupted on smaller screens.

**So, my questions are**:

- Which iPhone screen size to choose, when starting making iOS app in
  order not to face headaches with constraints on other screens and to
  make pixel perfect UI?
- If I receive design prepared for iPhone X screen, can I prepare it
  firstly for iPhone SE screen and will it be displayed correctly on
  bigger screens in this case?
- What are screen sizes you use in your projects most frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no difference in choosing which 1 , what you need is to make your thoughts when making constraints to be generic , and that means every static width/height will appear similar in all devices , and every proportional 1 will look according to the device size , personally i like to use iphone 5 ( please forget about iphone 4 or you'll have to make the main view a scrollview because of the very small height of that device ) , also you can toggle the device to see how the constraints you set ( in the choosen 1 ) are look in the other device

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to 'choose' a size. This is just a display setting and you can change it at any time to preview your layout on different devices.

You need to make your constrains in a logical way that will naturally adapt when change screen sizes.